# how to build dynamic grid with JSON and angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to use AngularJS. Want to build table grid based on below JSON.

```
{
    "gridLayout": "4.4",
    "tmatrix": [{
            "id": "1.1",
            "periodId": "3",
            "classId": "5",
            "subjectId": "2",
            "teacherId": "Rob",
            "NoteId": "8"
        }, {
            "id": "2.4",
            "periodId": "3",
            "classId": "5",
            "subjectId": "2",
            "teacherId": "4",
            "NoteId": "8"
        }

    ]
}
```

`gridLayout` will be defining number of col.row for example `"gridLayout":"4.4"` mean 4 col & 4 row

Id will be defining position within `table` for example `"id":"1.3"` mean Col=1.Row=3

how to capture position of block within table.

```
|------|------|------|------|
| 1.1  | 2.x  | 3.x  | 4.x  |
|(Rod) |      |      |      |
|------|------|------|------|
| 1.x  |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |
|------|------|------|------|
| 1.x  |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |
|------|------|------|------|
| 1.x  | 2.4  |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |
|------|------|------|------|
```

Can anyone give some idea how to do this or any in plug-in build directive

Comment: Do you have any example code that you have tried?

Comment: take a look at already created grid plungin https://www.google.fr/search?q=angular+grid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Sb6TVt6pFYKVaNv3tvgC

Comment: there is a very well designed grid called angular ui-grid. Check it out .http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example

http://plnkr.co/edit/fQOUPAmuh6MqMtmrNLKM?p=preview

```
<table >
    <tr ng-repeat="r in range(0,row)">
      <td ng-repeat="c in range(0,col)" ng-click="clickon(c+1,r+1)"> {{getDataForID(c+1 , r+1) |json}}  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
 .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.data =  [{
            "id": "1.1",
            "periodId": "3",
            "classId": "5",
            "subjectId": "2",
            "teacherId": "4",
            "NoteId": "8"
        }, {
            "id": "2.4",
            "periodId": "3",
            "classId": "5",
            "subjectId": "2",
            "teacherId": "4",
            "NoteId": "8"
        }
  ];



   $scope.row = 4;
   $scope.col = 6;

   $scope.range = function(min, max, step) {
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
        input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  };

   $scope.clickon = function(c,r){
     console.log(c +  ' / ' + r);
   }

   $scope.getDataForID = function (c,r){
     for(var i in $scope.data){
       if($scope.data[i]["id"]== c+'.'+r){
         return $scope.data[i];
       }
     }
     return c+'.'+r
   }
});
```

Comment: How to plot data base on ID as above JSON? My target is to plot data for example Id:2.4 in col 2 row 4. ?

Comment: try the plunker and open the console (F12 ) . when you click on a number it log the col and row with the function `clickon`. what do you mean by "plot" ??

Comment: Oh OK!. By plot I mean, I want to show subjectId=2, teacherId=4 against id value if id=1.1 (row 1, col 1) or if id=2.4 (row 2, col 4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100395/discussion-between-fresher-and-alainib).

Comment: @Alainlb : Is it possible for you to help me with another one ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842377